# Why the rtsp stream can be opened in smplayer gui instead of cli?

Tags: video, mpv

The rtsp url for my home ip camera is such format `rtsp://admin:xxxx@192.168.1.80:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0`.I can open it with `SMPlayer`'s gui window.
Why can't it be open with `SMPlayer`'s cli?

```
smplayer  rtsp://admin:xxxx@192.168.31.80:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0
```

[image]

```
/usr/bin/mpv --no-config --no-quiet --terminal --no-msg-color --input-ipc-server=/tmp/smplayer-mpv-44c1 --msg-level=ffmpeg/demuxer=error --no-fs --hwdec=no --sub-auto=fuzzy --no-input-default-bindings --input-vo-keyboard=no --no-input-cursor --cursor-autohide=no --no-keepaspect --wid=69206033 --monitorpixelaspect=1 --osd-level=1 --osd-scale=1 --osd-bar-align-y=0.6 --sub-ass --embeddedfonts --sub-ass-line-spacing=0 --sub-scale=1 --sub-font=Arial --sub-color=#ffffffff --sub-shadow-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-size=0.75 --sub-shadow-offset=2.5 --sub-font-size=50 --sub-bold=no --sub-italic=no --sub-margin-y=8 --sub-margin-x=20 --sub-codepage=ISO-8859-1 --sub-pos=100 --volume=55 --cache=auto --screenshot-template=cap_%F_%p_%02n --screenshot-format=jpg --screenshot-directory=/home/debian/Pictures/smplayer_screenshots --audio-pitch-correction=yes --volume-max=110 --ytdl --term-playing-msg=MPV_VERSION=${=mpv-version:}
INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH=${=width}
INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT=${=height}
INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT=${=video-params/aspect}
INFO_VIDEO_FPS=${=container-fps:${=fps}}
INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT=${=video-format}
INFO_VIDEO_CODEC=${=video-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=${=audio-codec-name}
INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=${=audio-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_RATE=${=audio-params/samplerate}
INFO_AUDIO_NCH=${=audio-params/channel-count}
INFO_LENGTH=${=duration:${=length}}
INFO_DEMUXER=${=current-demuxer:${=demuxer}}
INFO_SEEKABLE=${=seekable}
INFO_TITLES=${=disc-titles}
INFO_CHAPTERS=${=chapters}
INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=${=track-list/count}
METADATA_TITLE=${metadata/by-key/title:}
METADATA_ARTIST=${metadata/by-key/artist:}
METADATA_ALBUM=${metadata/by-key/album:}
METADATA_GENRE=${metadata/by-key/genre:}
METADATA_DATE=${metadata/by-key/date:}
METADATA_TRACK=${metadata/by-key/track:}
METADATA_COPYRIGHT=${metadata/by-key/copyright:}
INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=${=media-title:}
INFO_STREAM_PATH=${stream-path}
 --audio-client-name=SMPlayer --term-status-msg=STATUS: ${=time-pos} / ${=duration:${=length:0}} P: ${=pause} B: ${=paused-for-cache} I: ${=core-idle} VB: ${=video-bitrate:0} AB: ${=audio-bitrate:0} 
rtsp://admin:xxxx@192.168.31.80:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1

[ffmpeg/demuxer] rtsp: method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Not Found
[lavf] avformat_open_input() failed
Failed to recognize file format.
Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell is probably parsing the `&` character.

Try quoting the argument:

```
smplayer 'rtsp://admin:xxxx@192.168.31.80:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0'
```